# async return the simpleRestProvider in react admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

simple way to import dataProvider

```
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider(apiHost, httpClient);
export default dataProvider;
```

How can to export async?

```
export default async function () {
   return simpleRestProvider(apiHost, httpClient);
};
```

by using in this I get a error in admin page where I need getList from the dataProvider

*The response to 'getList' must be like { data: ... }, but the received response does not have a 'data' key. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getList'.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your dataProvider in an effect:

```
const MyAdmin = () => {
    const [dataProvider, setDataProvider] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataProvider().then(dataProvider => setDataProvider(dataProvider));
    }, []);

    if (!dataProvider) {
        return null; // or a loading page, whatever
    }

    return (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
            // ...
        </Admin>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax, function name is missing, might be that is issue, i hope after adding correct syntax of export function code will work for sure,

```
export default async function dataProvider() {
   return await simpleRestProvider(apiHost, httpClient);
};

import { dataProvider } from 'your_path_here';
```

or you can expor with this syntax,

```
export const dataProvider = async () => {        
    return await simpleRestProvider(apiHost, httpClient);
};
```

Comment: nothing changes, the error is the same

Comment: A function name is optional. It's called an anonymous function. It's less common to see them using the `function` keyword (more commonly using arrow functions) but they are both valid.

Comment: oh glad to know it, so sorry maybe im wrong here